# how to implement osgi configuration in karaf?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, karaf

I've written a OSGi service factory. want to define configuration for each instances of the service in Karaf. Below are the questions I've.
1. Where to define bundle specific .cfg in Karaf? I've seen answers that it should be in /etc or can be implemented via fileinstall. Still couldn't get a clear step by step procedure from implementation perspective. Need a step by step solution for the same.
2. If we've different configuration for every other environment for each service, how to maintain the same. Is there any ideal approach for the same?

Comment: Thanks @NeilBartlett for your response. I've created servicefactory class. Also, I created a config file <service-pid>-<instance> under the same project. I've defined the config file as a karaf feature definition. How to deploy those config file automatically into /etc folder ? Could you please share any working example for the same.

Comment: A `ServiceFactory`?? That sounds wrong. They are not used for Configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ManagedServiceFactory. For the factory, I created couple of config files. Am not sure how to deploy those into etc folder?

Comment: Are you asking how to copy some files into a folder?

Comment: I want to deploy all those configuration files automatically into karaf etc folder. Don't want to copy those files manually into etc folder.

Comment: So maybe you need a cron job?

Comment: Can't we achieve it via maven & karaf feature definition?

Comment: Achieve what? You've said almost nothing about what you actually want to do.

Comment: I want to deploy .cfg files of those managedservicefactory via maven & karaf feature definition into karaf etc folder. Is there a way to do the same?

Comment: The same what? I don't understand. You want to copy some files but you prefer to use a maven plugin than the `cp` command?